# Displaying a JavaScript variable multiple times on one page with classes

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game, I'm mostly displaying data like so:

```
document.getElementById("p1_TickStat").innerHTML = NumFix(1 * master.p1_Boost);
```

This works well for singular stats, but I want to be able to show the same variable stat on multiple sections of the page.

I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("p1_TickStat").innerHTML = NumFix(1 * master.p1_Boost);
```

With:

```
<b class="p1_TickStat">x</b>
```

But that doesn't work. I understand .getElementsByClassName() uses arrays instead, but for displaying a single stat I'm not sure how to write it.
Thanks.

edit: Also tried something like this but not having it.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("p1_TickStat");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
elements[i].innerHTML = NumFix(1 * master.p1_Boost);
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` (note the plural `getElements` in the name) returns a collection of elements. You'll need to loop through and modify each element within it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski why don't you write that as an answer?

Comment: For your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33857718/2): jQuery defines the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method for its collections to set the `innerHTML` of all matched elements – `$("p1_TickStat").html(NumFix(1 * master.p1_Boost));`

Comment: Sorry new to the site, i removed that jQuery from my main post with something else I tried. Now I tried the jQuery you posted but it's not having it.

     $(".p1_TickStat").each(function(){
    var update;
           update = $("p1_TickStat").html(NumFix(1 * master.p1_Boost));
    });

Comment: For your latest edit, can you expand on the snippet? Does it find the elements you expect it to – `elements.length > 0`? You may checkout the possible reasons and solutions described in [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: $(".p1_TickStat").html(NumFix(1*master.p1_Boost));

Comment: The html method works directly on every element of the matched set

Comment: Ooo it seems to be working now with the snippet I edited in to the main post. Thanks for your help Jonathan.